# How can I use HTML::Template without creating separate files for each template?

Tags: perl, perl-module

The normal way of using `HTML::Template` is as follows:

main file:

```
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'secret.tmpl');
$template->param(SECRET_MESSAGE => $bar);
print $template->output;
```

secret.tmpl:

```
<h1>Hello <TMPL_VAR NAME=SECRET_MESSAGE></h1>
```

The question is, can I use that template engine without creating separate files - i.e., generating template's content on the fly?

Or maybe it's possible with any other modules?

Comment: It's meaningless to advise something else without knowing what exactly is wrong with `HTML::Template` is not acceptable, don't you think?

Comment: I think  first we should create secret.tmpl file and we pass values to it.

Comment: Ah, you mean you don't want to use separate files for templates? But that's not necessary: you can use templates stored in vars, like shown in [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Template#new). Check `new_scalar_ref` and `new_array_ref` examples.

Comment: Glad to help, should I make this an answer for you to accept? )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with `HTML::Template`: its [constructor](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTemplate#new) works with templates stored either in scalar (as whole block of text) or in array (line by line). Like this:

```
my $t_from_scalar = HTML::Template->new(
    scalarref => $ref_to_template_text,
    option    => 'value',
);

my $t_from_array_of_lines = HTML::Template->new(
    arrayref => $ref_to_array_of_lines,
    option    => 'value',
);
```

In fact, there are two specific constructor methods for these cases:

```
my $t_from_scalar = HTML::Template->new_scalar_ref(
  $ref_to_template_text, option => 'value');

my $t_from_array_of_lines = HTML::Template->new_array_ref(
  $ref_to_array_of_lines, option => 'value');
```

Comment: what does option specify.?

Comment: Did you check the documentation linked? You can initialize template with different options. Examples show how exactly this should be done.

Comment: @pavan: `option => 'value'` is a placeholder for any of the *real* options that are available and described in the documentation. You can supply several options and values here, or if you want the default behaviour then you should omit it.